# Margin between list rows disappears while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm using a cards-UI layout in my app. On my physical device (android 2.3), It shows fine when the list is not scrolling:

[image]

But while I'm scrolling the list, the margin suddenly disappears:

[image]

Strangely, it **doesn't** happen on the AVD.

Does anyone know what's causing this and how can I solve this?

*Note:* If any part of the code helps, please comment so I can add them.

Comment: I think this is device issue which device are using ?

Comment: @Haresh, I'm using Galaxy Mini.